# Unity: Cannot Load/Save Player Pos

Tags: unity-game-engine

So, in Unity I am trying to load the player's position from PlayerPrefs.
LOAD FUNCTION

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using CI.QuickSave;

public class RELoadSave : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject Player;

    public float x, y, z;
    private bool saving = false;

    private int Mode = 0;
    private Vector3 coordsem;
    private int count;

    protected FileInfo theSourceFile = null;
    protected StreamReader reader = null;
    protected string text = " "; // assigned to allow first line to be read below

    public Button btn;
    void Start()
    {
        x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x");
        y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("y");
        z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("z");

        Vector3 LoadPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
        Player.transform.position = LoadPosition;
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        
    }

    void Update()
    {
        
    }
    public void ResetScene()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name);
        

    }

}
```

SAVE FUNCTION

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.IO;
using TMPro;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using CI.QuickSave;

public class SaveGame : MonoBehaviour
{
public float coordse;

public float x, y, z;

public GameObject Player;

// Start is called bsefore the first frame update
void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}

public void SaveGameCore()
{
    x = Player.transform.position.x;
    y = Player.transform.position.y;
    z = Player.transform.position.z;

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("x", x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("y", y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("z", z);

}
```

}

Things to note:

- these functions are NOT called inside the player
- running Unity 2019
  This is meant to be applicable to a 3d FPS game, taht is what the code is for not a 2d game. BUT I am confused, but I probally made a simple mistake. If it is not replacatable, I can upload *small* assets from the game. It should be working but it isn't. The player also can only collide with 2d box coliders if that helps.

Comment: Are you loading the position at the same time you are loading the scene (as shown above)?  You will need to load the position data from the newly loaded scene, not the currently loaded scene.  Comment out the LoadScene portion of the top code snip (for testing purposes) and it should load/set the data as expected.

Comment: k i will test that

Answer (score 1):

I checked your code and everything works fine

```
public float x,y,z;
public GameObject Player;
public Vector3 LoadPosition;
public void Save()
{
    x = Player.transform.position.x;
    y = Player.transform.position.y;
    z = Player.transform.position.z;

    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("x_", x);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("y_", y);
    PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("z_", z);

}
public void Load()
{
    x = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("x_");
    y = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("y_");
    z = PlayerPrefs.GetFloat("z_");

    LoadPosition = new Vector3(x, y, z);
    Player.transform.position = LoadPosition;
}
```

The problem may be related to the method of calling save or laod

Perhaps the problem is with the version of the unity you have, this is an **unlikely possibility**

Anyway, you can do without PlayerPrefs by saving the player data (Positino) in a text file inside the folder

Take a look at [this](https://www.raywenderlich.com/418-how-to-save-and-load-a-game-in-unity) reference for saving and Load

Comment: `the remaining code stops working` that is not really true. It is `c#` after all and the remaining code will run to end ... it just has no effect really as it would affect the current scene not the newly loaded one. The actually scene change is happening at the end of the frame / before the next frame

Comment: hmm it still does not work...?

Comment: True, it completes the scene until the end, but when the other scene is loaded, the variables return to their default value, Anyway, please attach the complete code as I mentioned before because the code works for me without problems

Comment: k full code will be uploaded

Comment: I EDIT the answer, I hope you find a solution to your problem as soon as possible